# A more efficient way of moving an array of C strings into Java space

Tags: java, c, arrays, string, java-native-interface

Let's say I have an array of C strings with N elements. My goal is to pass that array into a Java function using the JNI and return a new string array of equal length back to C space. At present I am doing the following:

- Using NewObjectArray to generate a Java Object array of length N.
- Calling NewStringUTF/SetObjectArray N times, to box each individual C string into the Java Object array.
- Invoking copyStrArr (source below).
- Allocating a length N array of (char *) with malloc.
- Calling GetObjectArrayElement/GetStringUTFChars N times, to unbox each individual Java String from the returned Java Object array.

For reference, the Java code looks like this:

```
public static String[] copyStrArr(String []inArr)
{
    String []outArr = new String[inArr.length];
    for(int _i = 0; _i < outArr.length; _i++) {
        outArr[_i] = inArr[_i]; /* Normally real work would be done here */
    }
    return outArr;
}
```

In the "real" case actual work would be done inside the for loop, but for benchmarking we're just making a copy of the data.

For large values of N this is slow. Ungodly slow. When moving a similarly sized array of ints or doubles from C to Java and back it runs ~70x faster than the String[] case. about 99.5% of the time is spent boxing and unboxing the data. In the primitive case the JNI offers {Set,Get}ArrayRegion functions to batch copy primitive arrays from C space to Java space and back, which is much faster.

It has been suggested I use a byte[] as an intermediary to get the data into Java space, and then do the individual String Object boxing in Java (where the JVM can optimize things). Benchmarks have shown that this performs slightly worse than the original test, moving much of the overhead into Java. Part of this might be that I may not be optimally unboxing/boxing the byte[] in Java. I am doing the following:

- Allocating a sufficiently large byte[] with NewByteArray
- Calling SetByteArrayRegion N times to populate the byte[]
- Invoking copyBytArray (source below)
- Calling GetByteArrayRegion and copying the whole result back into C space
- Allocating a sufficiently large array of (char *)
- Copying each of the N Strings out of the result into the newly allocated array.

My Java code looks like this:

```
public static byte[] copyBytArr(byte []inArr)
{
    String[] tokInArr = new String(inArr, UTF8_CHARSET).split("\0");
    String []tokOutArr = new String[tokInArr.length];
    int len = 0;
    for(int _i = 0; _i < tokOutArr.length; _i++) {
        tokOutArr[_i] = tokInArr[_i]; /* Normally real work would be done here */
        len += (tokInArr[_i].length() + 1);
    }
    byte[] outArr = new byte[len];
    int _j = 0;
    for(int _i = 0; _i < tokOutArr.length; _i++) {
        byte[] bytes = tokOutArr[_i].getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
        for(int _k = 0; _k < bytes.length; _k++) {
            outArr[_j++] = bytes[_k];
        }
        outArr[_j++] = '\0';
    }
    return outArr;
}
```

In this test about 55% of the overhead was spent in Java, and the rest was spent boxing/unboxing.

It has been suggested that some of my overhead is related to the fact that I an using UTF-8 data in C, since Java uses UTF-16. This is unavoidable.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I might go about this more efficiently?

Comment: Moving large amounts of data is always slow, and moving anything across the JNI boundary is slow. Do you really have to do that at all?

Comment: can u replace String object with char or something? because primitive type process faster than object in JVM

Comment: @Radiodef I wouldn't want my name associated with any claim that 'nothing in JNI is efficient'. What's inefficient is moving data across the JNI boundary, and that's because it *is* data movement. If you were in 100% Java or 100% C you wouldn't have to move anything. Most things in JNI are extremely efficient, *too* efficient in some cases as there is no error checking.

Comment: @EJP The nature of the project requires movement of relatively large data from memory managed by C into the JVM. This is a fundamental requirement and cannot be avoided. The issue is that moving character data in (as Strings) is 50-70x slower than moving int/double data.

Comment: @user4127 Sending in a char[][] is similarly inefficient as you need to construct an Object[] and populate it with char[]. Sending a delimited char[] and turning that into a String in Java is effectively what's being done in the second example.

Comment: @Radiodef That is what I am doing in my second example, I am creating a large byte[], passing that (quite quickly) into Java, and then turning that delimited byte[] into a String[] in Java. This procedure is about as inefficient as the first example.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is allocation of many string objects. In order to get real performance you need to just interchange large byte[] and use Wrapper Classes "pointing" to the byte array for String processing. As long you are creating String Objects from C chars[] back and forth, you won't get real throughput.

FST is doing something similar with the "StructString" class to operate on byte[] data without the need to create "real" Objects.

To speed up dataexchange further you might want to create shared memory using memory mapped files and access this via Unsafe or ByteBuffers.

Comment: I agree that most of the overhead is related to boxing and unboxing of Strings. We could pass the large delimited byte[] as well as an int[] which can act as an index vector into the byte[]. So delimitedByteArr[indexArr[i]] points to the first byte of the i-th string. Unfortunately, that may not be a reasonable compromise (our requirements may restrict us to ending up with a String[] when all is said and done). If we are going to have better throughput that requirement may need to be reviewed.

Comment: Its not "boxing" its allocation of String objects and char[] array objects (contained by String class).
How big is your "N" ?
Transfer of like 500 MB per second is not an issue (without any processing of this data :-)) )

Comment: @R-Moeller N can range from 4 million to 100 million. The size of each element can range from one to ~255 bytes, though there will be some examples of much wider data being passed through this interface. On the low we're working with a handful of megabytes, on the high side tens of gigabytes. We're currently seeing a 70x difference in speed between the int[] case and the String[] case, which is worrisome. The time it takes to Object-ify and unObject-ify 10 million char[]'s totaling in 78MB of data is ~5s, which is very slow. 10 million ints totaling in 38MB of data takes ~67ms.

Comment: @TheGeneral With this amount of data forget any solution requiring massive object allocation. Best approach should be to allocate a big byte buffer once and reuse this to pass data chunk-wise. Use wrappers to make data more accessible ..